# How do I get /mylink#sectionid to work in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

If I wasn't using angular, then the route mylink would be loaded, then the browser would scroll down to the sectionid section.

In Angular it doesn't scroll. I read some completely crazy whacky solutions involving injecting multiple modules and having crazy unique URLs. I refuse to do things like this.

I want my href values to remain standard. Is there any way in Angular to do this?

Keep in mind, if "mylink" was already loaded, then the links work fine, but if I'm on a different page, say "home", then I navigate to mylink#sectionid, then the scrolling won't occur.

(I mean... if Angular can't do this, I would consider that a bug. It'd be absurd to not support a regularly used syntax since the 90s that is still used today)

EDIT: I think the issue may be the amount of AJAX on this website.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, you will need to inject in `$anchorScroll` into your controller

The [example from the angular site](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll):

```
function ScrollCtrl($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.gotoBottom = function (){
    // set the location.hash to the id of
    // the element you wish to scroll to.
    $location.hash('bottom');

    // call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();
  };
}
```

From anther route you could handle this via  parameter being passed into the route and scroll upon initialization based upon the route param.

Comment: And href attribute value could still be "/mylink#sectionid" or does it now need to call the angular function gotoBottom on ng-click?

I'm looking for a solution that employs the basic premise of anchor tags invented 2 decades ago.

Comment: I don't believe so, angular is basically hijacking the hash tag mechanism of URL's in order to provide client side routing between different view which in my opinion is a solid trade-in for being able to scroll within the page with no code. That being said, you could probably create a directive that will handle the click event of an anchor tag to call the code I described above in my answer.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll see if anyone else has any idea, otherwise I'll investigate that option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of my solution, but I listen to onRouteChange, then inject anchorScroll and simply call anchorScroll after a 1000 ms timeout and because the hash is already set nothing more needs to be done. [giving time for all angular stuff to work its self out (the site I'm working on has entirely too much AJAX, but I don't have control of the data yet, so there is nothing I can do about that)]

Anywho, manually initiating anchor scroll works. If anyone knows a better way to do this, that'd be swell.